# Filter images from Gallery app programmatically

Tags: android, android-gallery

I'm programmatically opening images from an internal app folder in android's default Gallery app, but I need to filter those images by name (only show in the gallery the ones that its names start by a string). Is there a way to do that? Any suggestion would be very appreciated.

This is what I tried so far:

```
@Override
    public void onMediaScannerConnected() {

        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/images/" + files[files.length - 1];
        connection.scanFile(path, null);

    }



    @Override
    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {

        if (uri != null){

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(uri);

            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

        connection.disconnect();
        connection = null;

    }
```

This opens gallery app with all the images in that folder, I need to filter those by name

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto Maybe his question is not well formatted, he didn't include his codes too. But he has asked it in the right place, it's about developing and not about Android. Please double check before closing.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto I already included what I was working on. Any help would be appreciated